# XCODE fail to load platform

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to learn iphone programming and I have just upgraded xcode to version 3.2.4 (and to iOS 4.1).

When I create a new project I get the "Internal error" seen below. What is wrong? (by the way, I can't see any message in the console)

```
Internal Error

File:   /SourceCache/DevToolsBase/DevToolsBase-1705/pbxcore/Target.subproj/PBXTarget.m
Line:   1603
Object: <PBXNativeTarget:0x20088e7c0>
Method: createPropertyExpansionContextWithBuildState:

Platform failed to completely load.  Examine Console Log for error messages.
```

Comment: I have now reinstalled xcode (from the same downloaded image) and now it works fine! (I don't know why but I have a limited disk space that may have caused some problems during the first installation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same happened to me, and I fixed in the same way. Reinstaling from the same dowload image.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is follow the directive in the error message and check the console log.  To do so, choose Run -> Console (or press Shift-Command-R).  Read any displayed error messages.  If you can't get to the root of the problem from there, post the console log, and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you! My log was empty, but I have now reinstalled xcode (from the same downloaded image) and now it works fine! (I don't know why but I have a limited disk space that may have caused some problems during the first installation).

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting the exact same message with the version of the SDK that I downloaded yesterday.  Here's what I get in the console.  I verified that /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin exists, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

There were about 20 copies of the first message, I only pasted in one.

11/14/10 9:12:14 AM Xcode[8973] WARNING: Failed to load plugin at: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin, skipping.  Could not load bundle.

11/14/10 9:12:14 AM Xcode[8973] Platform validation failed for Class 'XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext'
11/14/10 9:12:14 AM Xcode[8973] [MT] File:  /SourceCache/DevToolsBase/DevToolsBase-1705/pbxcore/Target.subproj/PBXTarget.m
Line:   1603
Object: 
Method: createPropertyExpansionContextWithBuildState:

Platform failed to completely load.  Examine Console Log for error messages.
Backtrace:

0  0x000000010099fe19 -[PBXAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DevToolsInterface)

1  0x00000001002dab1f _XCAssertionFailureHandler (in DevToolsCore)

2  0x00000001000e9ca1 -[PBXTarget createPropertyExpansionContextWithBuildState:] (in DevToolsCore)

3  0x00000001000e9212 -[PBXTarget createPropertyExpansionContextWithBuildAction:configurationName:] (in DevToolsCore)

4  0x00000001000e8ca2 -[PBXTarget cachedPropertyExpansionContextForConfigurationNamed:] (in DevToolsCore)

5  0x00000001000e8b33 -[PBXTarget expandedValueForString:forConfigurationNamed:] (in DevToolsCore)

6  0x00000001000f8c79 -[PBXProject _validArchsMayHaveChanged:] (in DevToolsCore)

7  0x00000001000f69a0 -[PBXProject _unarchiverDidFinishUnarchiving:] (in DevToolsCore)

8  0x00007fff819f8a66 _nsnote_callback (in Foundation)

9  0x00007fff87d7e000 __CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)

10  0x00007fff87d6a578 _CFXNotificationPostNotification (in CoreFoundation)

11  0x00007fff819ef9ce -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)

12  0x00000001000d2cbb -[PBXPListUnarchiver decodeRootObject] (in DevToolsCore)

13  0x00000001000d0da4 +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)

14  0x00000001000d0003 +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)

15  0x0000000100963460 -[PBXProjectTemplateClonerWizard _instantiateASCIIMacroTemplateWithContext:] (in DevToolsInterface)

16  0x00000001009634f7 -[PBXProjectTemplateClonerWizard _instantiateTemplateWithContext:] (in DevToolsInterface)

17  0x00000001009d29d6 -[PBXFileCopyingWizard _finishCopyingTemplate:filesToPreserve:] (in DevToolsInterface)

18  0x00000001009d2895 -[PBXFileCopyingWizard _checkForOverwritingFiles:] (in DevToolsInterface)

19  0x00000001009400f1 -[PBXProjectWizard finish] (in DevToolsInterface)

20  0x000000010093be24 -[PBXProjectWizardChooserWizard sheetDidEndWithReturnCode:fileSystemLocations:contextInfo:] (in DevToolsInterface)

21  0x00000001008e3fda +[PBXOpenSavePanelHelper sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:] (in DevToolsInterface)

22  0x00007fff86bd9946 -[NSSavePanel _didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:] (in AppKit)

23  0x00007fff8697fbd1 -[NSApplication endSheet:returnCode:] (in AppKit)

24  0x00007fff86891e9a -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)

25  0x00007fff86891df9 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] (in AppKit)

26  0x00007fff8691d76b -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)

27  0x00007fff8694e2aa -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)

28  0x00007fff8691c215 -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)

29  0x00007fff8683634f -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)

30  0x00007fff8676ba86 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)

31  0x00000001007fc21c -[PBXExtendedApplication sendEvent:] (in DevToolsInterface)

32  0x00007fff867024da -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)

33  0x00007fff866fb1a8 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)

34  0x00000001000017b4

Comment: OK, reinstalling the SDK worked for me too.  Kind of weird you have to install it twice but there you go.