# Xcode error when start

Tags: xcode

When I open xocde, it pops a window, and tells me:

```
"xcode scanning for plug-ins failed.
You may not have appropriate permission to read or load installed plug-ins."
```

I don't know what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to reinstall the xcode,See the link for solution that may help you to resolve the problem

[XCODE fail to load platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178282/xcode-fail-to-load-platform)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two versions of XCode installed ? 
If yes then ideally you should install the XCode with different versions in different directories. May be you installed lower version of XCode on top of higher version and then trying to launch the XCode.

Answer (score 0):

- Quit the xCode.
- Reinstall all plug-ins for xcode. It was helpfully for me.
- reinstall xcode if nothing help..

Comment: Hi,thank your answer.can you tell me more about reinstall plug-ins for xcode? I reinstall a CodePilot2 plug-in,but nothing help.